# Install Odespy on Windows 64 bit with Fortran Solvers

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit

I tried to install odespy (https://github.com/hplgit/odespy) on Windows 7 x64 with the Anaconda Python distribution version 3.4. If I start the installation with

```
python setup.py install --no-fortran
```

the installation is no problem. Because I need the additional Fortran solvers and there is a message "Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64", I have installed Visual Studio 2010. When I start the compilation with

```
python setup.py build --compiler=msvc
```

I get errors from the linker like this:

```
_odepack.lib(opkda2.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_runtime_error_at_odepack.lib(solve_odepack.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_os_error referenced in function solve__odepack.lib(solve_odepack.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_compare_string referenced in function solve_
```

I have uploaded the full compiling output here:
http://n.ethz.ch/~faheller/download/misc/output_compilation_odespy.txt

Does someone know were the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Odespy has not been ported to Python3. Use Python27. (https://github.com/hplgit/odespy/issues/5)